# Como adicionar botões dinâmicos por página carregada?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Minha controller chama a factory `Action` e adiciona botões na página que estou carregando, veja a baixo a controller:

```
class AgenciesListController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor(Action) {
    this.action = Action;

    this.action.addButton({
      title: 'Nova Agência',
      state: 'agencies.new'
    });
  }
}

export default AgenciesListController;
```

A factory `Action`, simples, tem as funções de adicionar e pegar todos os botões adicionados:

```
const ActionFactory = () => {
  let buttons = [];

  return {
    addButton: (button) => buttons.push(button),
    getButtons: () => buttons
  };
};

export default ActionFactory;
```

Desejo que ao mudar de página, somente apresente os botões da página selecionada, se uma página não tiver botões em sua controller, nada deve ser apresentado.

O código acima trás um comportamento indesejado adicionando novos botões toda vez que a pagina é selecionada pelo menu.

Devo resetar o array `buttons` toda vez que mudar de página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor solução e ainda com suporte a uma futura configuração é utilizando um Provider. Como estou utilizando [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), decidi colocar as configurações de botões dinâmico diretamente na criação da rota, veja um exemplo:

```
.state('agencies.list', {
  url: '/list',
  component: 'agenciesList',
  data: {
    action: {
      buttons: [{
        title: 'Nova Agência',
        state: 'agencies.new'
      }]
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    /* @ngInject */
    agencies: Api => Api.all('agencies').getList()
  }
})
```

A controller do componente ficou assim:

```
import { registerListenerOnce } from './action.utils.js';

class ActionController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor($action, $rootScope) {
    this.action = $action;
    this.scope = $rootScope;
  }

  $postLink() {
    const renderAction = () => {
      this.buttons = this.action.getButtons();
    };

    registerListenerOnce('ActionDirective.$viewContentLoaded', this.scope, '$viewContentLoaded', () => {
      renderAction();
    });

    renderAction();
  }
}

export default ActionController;
```

Criei uma classe `utils` onde tem os registros dos `listeners`:

```
let $registeredListeners = {};

const registerListenerOnce = (tag, $rootScope, event, fn) => {
  let deregisterListenerFn = $registeredListeners[tag];

  if (deregisterListenerFn !== undefined) {
    deregisterListenerFn();
  }

  deregisterListenerFn = $rootScope.$on(event, fn);
  $registeredListeners[tag] = deregisterListenerFn;
};

export {
  registerListenerOnce
};
```

E o mais importante, o `provider`:

```
class ActionProvider {
  /* @ngInject */
  $get($state) {
    return {
      getButtons: () => {
        let current = $state.$current;
        let buttons = null;

        if (current.data.action) {
          buttons = current.data.action.buttons;
        }

        return buttons;
      }
    };
  }
}

export default ActionProvider;
```

Espero ajudar outros desenvolvedores com essa solução.